# IE6: window.onresize works on IIS, blows up on asp.net Dev Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer

**Update 1:**
Cannot reproduce this on a co-worker's computer (same setup as mine) so I assume this is a problem with my workstation and not a general one.

I'd appreciate it if someone would close this question as I don't have enough reputation to do it myself.

@MatthewMartin. Thanks for your comments :-)

---

**Update 2:**
Unlike my coworker, I have **VS90sp1-KB945140-ENU.exe (SP1)** and **VS90SP1-KB957912-x86.exe** (JS Intellisense hotfix) installed on my machine.  That *appears* to be the only difference between our setups.  I removed both of them, but that didn't solve my problem.

---

In my asp.net (C#) page is a little bit of Javascript to resize an object when the user resizes the window.

When I access the page using IE6 on my DEV server (IIS), it **works**.
When I access the page using IE6 via VS2008 using F5 or CTRL-F5 (both of which start the ASP.NET Development Server) it **fails**. It seems to enter an infinite loop of resizing where the `adjSpreadsheetSize` function fires the window.resize event, which invokes `adjSpreadsheetSize` ... Repeat ad infinitum

I see quite a few people out there complaining that IE6 can't properly handle onresize events, but nobody seems to be having this precise problem.

**Any idea why this code works on IIS but not on ASP.NET Development Server?**

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
[snip]
<head>
[snip]
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = adjSpreadsheetSize;
    window.onload = pageSetup;

    //Change spreadsheet size to fill the window (viewport) below the entry form
    function adjSpreadsheetSize() {
        var objSS = document.getElementById("OWC_data");
        var winWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var winHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        winHeight -= document.getElementById('form_body').offsetHeight;

        objSS.height = winHeight;
        objSS.width = winWidth;
        return false;
    }

    function pageSetup() {
        adjSpreadsheetSize();
    }
</script>

[snip]
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="rawdata.aspx" method="get">
<div id="form_body">
[snip]
</div>
</form>
<div id="OWC_container">
    <object id="OWC_data" classid="clsid:0002E559-0000-0000-C000-000000000046">
    </object>
</div>
```

My setup:

- WinXP Pro SP2
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM

  - Installed Edition: Professional
  - Microsoft Visual Basic 2008
  - Microsoft Visual C# 2008
  - Microsoft Visual C++ 2008
  - Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office
  - Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008
  - Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1
- The Website project lives on the DEV server (mapped as a local drive)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an activex object you're trying to load, maybe your MSIE is configured to trust http://localhost more than http://localhost:1235/foo ?

Other differences with IIS vs ASP.NET Development Server:

IIS only turns some files over to the aspnet filter, ASP.NET dev server turns all over to IIS.

Also, sometimes the change in port # will change behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I added
`alert("Viewport: " + document.documentElement.clientHeight + " -  formHeight: " + formHeight + " = " + winHeight);`

For some reason, the div "form_body" flips back and forth between "421" and "435" (difference of 14). So I added a border to try and see where the change occurs...
`<div style="border: solid 1px red;" id="form_body">`

And when the border is there, the resize works. Easily reproducible... add the border style, and the resize fires 3~5 times.  Remove the border and it repeatedly fires for as long as I care to sit and watch it.

WTF?